# p:ajaxStatus does not receive oncomplete event from lazy datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and trying to display a "loading" image while updating a lazy-loaded datatable. In the following AjaxStatus element, the "ajax-loader" image is displayed when datatable is updated by a commandButton action. However when ajax call and table update is completed, the image does not disappear. In other words onComplete event is not received.

```
<p:ajaxStatus style="width:260px;" id="ajaxStatusPanel">  
    <f:facet name="start">  
        <h:graphicImage value="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />  
    </f:facet>  

    <f:facet name="complete">  
        <h:outputText value="" />  
    </f:facet>  
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

Here is a portion of the form that contains the commandButton and the datatable:

```
<h:form> 

<p:panel toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="300" header="FILTER RESULTS">  
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>NAME: </td>
            <td><h:inputText value="#{personBean.personLazyData.paramName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PLACE OF BIRTH : </td>
            <td><h:inputText value="#{personBean.personLazyData.paramPlaceOfBirth}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <p:commandButton value="Update" global="true" 
                    actionListener="#{personBean.onFilterChanged}" 
                    update="personListTable"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p:panel>

<p:dataTable id="personListTable" rendered="#{personBean.superUser}" var="person" 
        value="#{personBean.personLazyData}" emptyMessage="Not found."
        paginator="true" rows="20" lazy="true" selection="#{personBean.selectedPersons}" global="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
        rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100">            

            <f:facet name="header">SURVEYS</f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />  

            <p:column headerText="ID" >
                <h:outputText value="#{person.id}"/>
            </p:column>      

            <p:column headerText="NAME" >
                <h:outputText value="#{person.name}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="SURNAME" >
                <h:outputText value="#{person.surname}" />
            </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Is there anybody who have faced a similar issue?

Another note: In cases where datatable is not rendered (or if I change rendered attribute to false), the loading image is displayed and disappeared for a very short while since no data is retrieved.

Comment: I've observed the same behaviour with BlockUI element:

<p:blockUI block="personListTable" trigger="personListTable">...</p:blockUI>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved when I updated primefaces version to 4.0